# Prove that the set of all unit vectors in a finite-dimensional normed vector space is compact.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional normed vector space and let $S=\left\{ v\in V:\left\Vert v\right\Vert =1\right\}$ , that is, the collection of all unit vectors in $V$. Prove that $S$ is compact. Is it possible to use the Heine-Borel theorem to prove this?

Comment: It is closed and bounded.

Comment: @OpenBall, are we not? Fix a basis in $V$ and you are in $\mathbb R^{\dim X}$ with some norm.

Answer (score 1):

Fix an inner product in $V$. With the inner-product norm it is isometric to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. In finite-dimensinonal vector spaces all norms are equivalent hence they generate the same topology. As the unit sphere is closed, it is also closed as a subset of the Euclidean space. You may then use the Heine-Borel theorem.